# Docker and Openproject compose - with own network bridge

Tags: docker, openproject

I set up a Docker host with rootless. Portainer is working fine and I also can start with the following compose file the openproject but only when I run it on the standard bridge network from docker.

I have created several network adapter on my docker host (debian). So i have there for example
ens1283 = 192.168.10.5
ens3283 = 192.168.50.11
Why: ens3283 has on the host of course a mac address which gives me the possibility to distribute a fixed ip.

Now I created a bridge on portainer with the following settings:

```
Nam  VLAN50FIX11
ID  2725cc96b95b7de962a5a69d3437e0b601f4606782ad97bffe8234166eaab93e 
Driver  bridge
Scope   local
Attachable  false
Internal    false
IPV4 Subnet - 172.17.11.0/16    IPV4 Gateway - 172.17.11.1
IPV4 IP range - 172.17.11.1/25  IPV4 Excluded Ips
Access control
Ownership   administrators
Network options
com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc    true
com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade  true
com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4 192.168.50.11
com.docker.network.bridge.name  VLAN50FIX11
com.docker.network.driver.mtu   1500
```

I also tried it with different network so: 192.168.50.0/24 and a lot other version.
But I had never luck I always got ERR_SS_PROTOCOL_ERROR in the browser. When I start the stack with the default bridge, it works fine.

Docker compose file:

---

version: '3.9'
services:
openproject:
hostname: SVGXXX-OPEN-01
image: openproject/community:12.1.5

```
networks:
  - VLAN50FIX11
ports:
  - 8181:80
  
container_name: openproject

environment:
  - PUID=1001
  - PGID=1001
  - SECRET_KEY_BASE=9jsdjkSKjf99847459Dg7956ds61
volumes:
  - /var/lib/containers/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata
  - /var/lib/containers/openproject/assets:/var/openproject/assets
restart: unless-stopped
```

networks:
VLAN50FIX11:
external: true

---

I always recieve: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I start the openproject stack.

What do I need to change?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to set

```
OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false
```

> disables the on-by-default HTTPS mode of OpenProject so you can access
> the instance over HTTP-only. For all production systems we strongly
> advise not to set this to false, and instead set up a proper TLS/SSL
> termination on your outer web server.

https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/docker/#all-in-one-container